# Install older versions of Python for testing on Mac OS X

Tags: python, version, installation

I have Mac OS X 10.5.7 with Python 2.5. I need to test a package I am working on with Python 2.3 for compatibility. I don't want to downgrade my whole system so is there a way to do an install of Python 2.3 that does not change the system python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two main options, install the python 2.3 from [macports](http://www.macports.org/) (easy) or install from source.

For macports, run `port install python23`

For the 2nd, you'll have to go to http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3.7/ to download the source tarball. Once you have that open a terminal and run `./configure --prefix /home/(your homedir)/software MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.5` then `make` and `make install`. This should place a separate install in the software directory that you can access directly.

Comment: MacPorts also includes a python23 (Python 2.3) package.

Comment: The tarball approach above is quite simple and works great on OS X for previous versions of Python.  I just installed 2.6.7 that way.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to use a virtual machine.

With something like VMWare Fusion or Virtualbox you could install a complete Linux system with Python2.3, and do your testing there. The advantage is that it would be completely sand-boxed, so wouldn't affect your main system at all.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://farmdev.com/thoughts/66/python-3-0-on-mac-os-x-alongside-2-6-2-5-etc-/) has useful information on building python from source.  It's talking about 3.0, but the advice will *probably* apply to 2.3 as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Fink package manager and simply to "fink install python2.3".

If you need Python 2.3 to be your default, you can simply change /sw/bin/python and /sw/bin/pydoc to point to the version you want (they sit in /sw/bin/).